# Best practice for handling WebServices' GetSomethingById-like methods in Silverlight

Tags: web-services, silverlight, .net-4.0

What would be the best practice for handling a -Completed event originating from a WebService method that was called multiple times, with the -Completed event being subscribed to that many times.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5311488/1151654) proposes to identify the result from the event args (in this example with e.Type but it can also be done with e.Result.Id or anything that can help identify what's needed).

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5322577/1151654), on the other hand, shows a client initialization for each call.

What's best to do ?

- Identify the result from its contents/additionnal info;
- Use multiple clients, one for each event-waiter;
- Something else?

The question is for .NET 4.0 and newer but if you have a "best practice" that works from earlier versions and is still viable feel free to tell anyway.

Answer (score 0):

One way that I have used before was to chain the web service calls. So when the first call completed I deregistered from the completed event and then registered to another or the same with a different callback method and so on... I know this was not perfect as approach but the delay was minimal not to say absent and it was less complex than having to manage many proxy instances. We did consider having multiple clients if you require the calls to be performed in parallel this is probably the way to go!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you're trying to do, you might want to create a class which represents each logical task that involves the web services. Create an instance of that class for each instance of the logical task, and give that class events.

The `sender` parameter of each event will be the instance of the wrapper class. You can then have one piece of code handle the events of each such logical thread, and the "logical thread" will contain all the state necessary.

Comment: Do you mean use multiple instances of the wrapper that all refer to the same instance of service ? How will these instance identify in their turn what's "their" answer ?

Comment: You're right. That doesn't work. Which version of .NET are you using?

Comment: This question is not for a specific version of the .NET but since it can indeed induce differences on webservices I'll edit my question to show that.